# Testclass trigger is not giving code coverage

Tags: apex, trigger, unit-test

I have written a triger on a custom Order object and a testclass which runs with succes but still dont have any codecoverage how do i assert this see my code:

```
trigger OrderTrigger on Order__c (after insert, after update) {

    if(Trigger.isAfter && Trigger.isInsert){

        //Trigger Handler for creating new Opportunity 
        //or relating order to existing opportunity
        OrderTriggerHandler orderTriggerHandlerInstance = new OrderTriggerHandler();
        orderTriggerHandlerInstance.afterInsert(Trigger.New);        
    }

    if(Trigger.isAfter && Trigger.isUpdate){

        List<Order__c> newOrderListToUpdate = new List<Order__c>();
        //Filter Order__c whose End_Date__c or orderAmount
        //field is Updated
        for(Order__c order : Trigger.New){

            Order__c oldOrder = Trigger.oldMap.get(Order.Id);
            if((order.End_Date__c != oldOrder.End_Date__c ||
                order.End_Date__c != Null ||                
               order.Order_Amount__c != oldOrder.Order_Amount__c) &&
           (order.Status__c == 'A'||
            order.Status__c == 'API'||
            order.Status__c == 'AUI'||
            order.Status__c == 'AX'||
            order.Status__c == 'L'||
            order.Status__c == 'LUG1'||
            order.Status__c == 'S'||
            order.Status__c == 'SUC') && order.Journal_Code__c != 'KLP'){
                newOrderListToUpdate.add(order);
            }
        }

        //Trigger Handler for creating new Opportunity 
        //or relating order to existing opportunity        
        if(!newOrderListToUpdate.isEmpty()){
            OrderTriggerHandler orderTriggerHandlerInstance = new OrderTriggerHandler();
            orderTriggerHandlerInstance.relateOpportunity(newOrderListToUpdate);
        }        
    }
}
```

Test class

```
@isTest
public class TestOderTrigger {


    static testMethod void trgOrderTest() {

        Profile profile = [Select Id From Profile where Name = 'System Administrator' limit 1];
        User usr1= new User();
        usr1.ProfileID = profile.Id;
        usr1.Username ='Test@Testemail.com'+ System.currentTimeMillis(); 
        usr1.LastName ='TestLastname';
        usr1.Email ='Test@Testemail.com';
        usr1.Alias ='TestAlia';
        usr1.TimeZoneSidKey ='TestCommunityNickname';
        usr1.CommunityNickname ='TestCommunityNickname';
        usr1.TimeZoneSidKey ='America/Los_Angeles';
        usr1.LocaleSidKey ='en_US';
        usr1.EmailEncodingKey ='UTF-8';
        usr1.LanguageLocaleKey ='en_US';
        insert usr1;
        System.runAs(usr1){




    // Create account
        Account testAccount = new Account(Name = 'Test Account');
        insert testAccount;

        system.debug(testAccount.id);


        // Create Contact
        Contact cont = new Contact();
        cont.FirstName='Test';
        cont.LastName='Test';
        cont.Accountid= testAccount.id;
        insert cont;

        system.debug(cont.id);

        // First, set up test price book entries.
        // Insert a test product.
        Product2 prod = new Product2(Name = 'Laptop X200', 
            Family = 'Hardware');
        insert prod;

        // Get standard price book ID.
        // This is available irrespective of the state of SeeAllData.
        Id pricebookId = Test.getStandardPricebookId();

        // 1. Insert a price book entry for the standard price book.
        // Standard price book entries require the standard price book ID we got earlier.
        PricebookEntry standardPrice = new PricebookEntry(
        Pricebook2Id = pricebookId, Product2Id = prod.Id,
        UnitPrice = 10000, IsActive = true);
        insert standardPrice;

        // Create a custom price book
        Pricebook2 customPB = new Pricebook2(Name='Custom Pricebook', isActive=true);
        insert customPB;

        // 2. Insert a price book entry with a custom price.
        PricebookEntry customPrice = new PricebookEntry(
            Pricebook2Id = customPB.Id, Product2Id = prod.Id,
            UnitPrice = 12000, IsActive = true);
        insert customPrice;

    // Create Opportunity
        Opportunity testOpportunity = new Opportunity();
        testOpportunity.CloseDate = System.today();
        testOpportunity.AccountId = testAccount.Id;
        testOpportunity.StageName = 'Prospecting';
        testOpportunity.Name = 'Test Opportunity';
        testOpportunity.Probability = 0;
        testOpportunity.CurrencyIsoCode = 'USD';
        testOpportunity.Type = 'Upsell';
        testOpportunity.Delegate_Admin__c = cont.id;
        testOpportunity.Pricebook2Id = customPB.id;
        insert testOpportunity; 

        system.debug('testOpportunitys'+testOpportunity.id);






        OpportunityLineItem oppLine = new OpportunityLineItem(pricebookentryid=customPrice.Id, TotalPrice = 12000 ,Quantity = 2, OpportunityID = testOpportunity.Id);
        insert oppLine;


    // Create Order    
        Order__c testOrder = new Order__c();
        testOrder.Name = 'test';
        testOrder.CurrencyIsoCode = 'USD';
        testOrder.Account_Name__c = testAccount.id;
        testOrder.Status__c = 'A';
        testOrder.End_Date__c = System.today()+1;
        testorder.Order_Amount__c = 5555;
        testorder.Journal_Code__c = 'AZ12345';
        testorder.Product__c = prod.Id; 
        testorder.Delegate_Admin__c = cont.id;
        insert testOrder;

  }  
  }   
}
```

Comment: Hi Jenssen, welcome to SFSE! Please take a moment to visit the [help], scroll through the [tour], and read [ask]. If you are trying to get tutelage on basic skills, the **[Trailhead](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/modules/apex_testing)** platform was tailor made for that purpose.

Comment: @Adrian thanks for your input I went trough the trailheads but I am still stuck maby you could piont me in the right direction I alredy tried: 'System.assert([SELECT Id FROM Order__c].size() != 0);   
        System.assert([SELECT Id FROM OpportunityLineItem].size() != 0); '

Comment: @Jenssen - You may want to go through trailhead again a well a covering some of the basics. an assert with a query will not fire any code and thus would not cause any code coverage as queries do not cause code to execute

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the test method you are inserting Order record.

So, it will cover only following lines in trigger

```
if(Trigger.isAfter && Trigger.isInsert){

        //Trigger Handler for creating new Opportunity 
        //or relating order to existing opportunity
        OrderTriggerHandler orderTriggerHandlerInstance = new OrderTriggerHandler();
        orderTriggerHandlerInstance.afterInsert(Trigger.New);        
    }
```

To cover, lines within  `if(Trigger.isAfter && Trigger.isUpdate){`, you need to update newly created Order record in test method.